# icpc C++11 with gcc stdlib

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++, icc

I am using icpc (non optional) and I am compiling with -std=c++0x so I can use lambas.

However when I do so it creates havok with gcc stdlib with features that one supports that the other doesn't.

I have tried defining

```
__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
```

but that didn't help.

So ideally what I am asking for is the ability to use the c++0x language features with the C++03 stdlib.

gcc 4.6

icc 12.1]

EDIT example of error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6.2/type_traits(74): error: identifier "constexpr" is undefined
    static constexpr _Tp                  value = __v;
           ^

/usr/include/c++/4.6.2/type_traits(74): error: expected a ";"
        static constexpr _Tp                  value = __v;
                                          ^

/usr/include/c++/4.6.2/type_traits(75): error: member "std::integral_constant<_Tp,      __v>::_Tp" is not a type name
    typedef _Tp                           value_type;
            ^

/usr/include/c++/4.6.2/type_traits(76): error: member "std::integral_constant<_Tp,     __v>::_Tp" is not a type name
        typedef integral_constant<_Tp, __v>   type;
                              ^

 /usr/include/c++/4.6.2/type_traits(77): error: identifier "constexpr" is undefined  
         constexpr operator value_type() { return value; }
         ^

 /usr/include/c++/4.6.2/type_traits(87): error: identifier "constexpr" is undefined
      constexpr _Tp integral_constant<_Tp, __v>::value;
```

Comment: "icpc" is the command to run the intel compiler. Much like g++.

Comment: icpc is a command to invoke Intel C++ Compiler. A very good optimizing compiler for different OS.

Comment: @mikithskegg good for intel systems that is, the generated binary disables many optimizations at runtime based on the cpu vendor id (instead of relying on the x86 feature bits, which it only uses if the cpu is "GenuineIntel").

Comment: Yes, but on Intel processors it can increase performance upto 30% in comparison with gcc. I often use it for my work.

Comment: @josefx SIMD optizations (specifically AVX in my case) are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors obviously point to C++11 code, so it sounds like you want to *prevent* the compiler from seeing any of that, such as with `-U__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` (the equivalent GCC option).

However, if ICC is defining this for you under `-std=c++0x`, then you should find out what version of the library you are supposed to use (or look for a library in your local ICC installation). It's far from certain that the C++03 library is sufficient to compile C++11 code.

Answer (score 0):

`icpc` only warns at such situation. Do not put attention on this. Everything will be compiled.

Comment: No it errors out, I have added an example of such in my edit.