# Compile with Intel 12.1.3 using gcc4.7 std library

Tags: c++, intel

I'm having the same problem described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527064/stdfunction-and-the-intel-compiler-version-11-1) post except I'm using Intel version 12.1.3. (`g++`'s header `<functional>` is protected with `#ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` which is not defined when icpc is used.)

Instead of using `boost::functional`, I wanted to install gcc4.7 and use it's std libraries.

In Ubuntu 11.10 I have `gcc4.6.1` but I also installed `gcc4.7` from the `gcc-snapshot` package.

Intel has the options `-gcc-name`, `-gxx-name`, and `-cxxlib`. 
So originally I compiled with:

`-std=c++0x -gcc-name=/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/bin/gcc -gxx-name=/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/bin/g++ -cxxlib=/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/`

but I get the error:

`icpc: error #10282: file
  '/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/bin/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/bin/g++' not found,
  generated based on '-cxxlib=/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/'`

So then I compiled with:

`-std=c++0x -gcc-name=./gcc -gxx-name=./g++ -cxxlib=/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/`.

But I still get the warnings and errors:

`Warning #2928: the __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ macro is disabled when using GNU version 4.6 with the c++0x option`

`error: namespace "std" has no member "function"`

The warning clearly says it's still using version 4.6. Does anybody know how to get Intel to use the correct libraries?

Comment: Maybe my previous question may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282461/icpc-c11-with-gcc-stdlib

Comment: I'm not sure it does, although it's along the same lines. For my purposes there should be a way to get the Intel compiler to use the correct gcc libraries - correct?

Comment: the best I could get was to be able to use C++11 language constructs like lambdas, however only use the C++03 stdlib (so no unordermap, random, chrono...).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you compile with gcc (or g++) with flags -v -Q you get a list of flags and defines.  It might help you see what gcc does so maybe you can use the same -D/-U in icpc.  also g++ -E will preprocess without compiling: you can get useful path information from that.